# How to save state of toggled nested menu items after page refresh?

Tags: javascript

I’m just starting to learn javascript so please bear with me if this is a silly question

I have a sidebar menu with layers of nested hidden child submenu items that can be toggled to be visible or not

It works, but their state reverts once the page reloads.

Is there a relatively simple way to save their state in localstorage so that it stays the same when the page refreshes?
What might that look like?

```
const todos = document.querySelectorAll(".todo");
const togglers = document.querySelectorAll(".toggler");

todos.forEach((todo) => {
  todo.addEventListener("click", () => {
    todo.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});

togglers.forEach((toggler) => {
  toggler.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toggler.classList.toggle("active");
    toggler.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul class="todos" id="todos">
      <div class="toggler">Resolve Exterior Herbs</div>
        <ul class="toggler-target">
        <li class="todo">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="http://tcm.school/herbs/resolve_exterior_herbs.html">Introduction</a></li>                  
          <div class="toggler">Dispel Wind Cold Herbs</div> 
          <ul class="toggler-target">
            <li class="todo">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="http://tcm.school/herbs/dispel_wind_cold_herbs.html">Introduction</a></li>
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Not *too* simple, but give id attribute to each node of menu and on every click store that array of "active" nodes as json of id's. Now, on page load restore the menu with active classes for the proper ids elements.

Comment: @ITgoldman How about just creating an array from NodeList (querySelectorAll result) and just refering indexes instead of attaching ids to all of the items? Order of nodes should be [preserved](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall)

Comment: That's a possibility. I was just assuming the menu might change structure in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty primitive solution that will help until you modify sidebar list items. It relies on order of items so if you check items 1 and 3 and add 1 more item in between of them - item1 will be toggled but item3 is now item4 and it will not be toggled, the new item3 will be. I guess you got what I mean.

```
const togglersKey = "sidebar_togglers";

const checkedTogglers = loadTogglersState();
const todos = document.querySelectorAll(".todo");
const togglers = document.querySelectorAll(".toggler");

todos.forEach((todo, i) => {
  todo.addEventListener("click", () => {
    todo.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});

togglers.forEach((toggler, i) => {
  if (checkedTogglers[i]) {
    toggler.classList.add("active");
    toggler.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
  }

  toggler.addEventListener("click", () => {
    checkedTogglers[i] = toggler.classList.toggle("active");
    toggler.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("active");
    saveTogglersState();
  });
});

function saveTogglersState() {
  localStorage.setItem(togglersKey, JSON.stringify(checkedTogglers));
}
function loadTogglersState() {
  const json = localStorage.getItem(togglersKey);
  if (!json) return [];
  return JSON.parse(json);
}
```

[image: Edit interesting-http-qfysq5]